# PHP mailer , attachment not found/detected - so, email not sent

Tags: php, attachment, phpmailer

I have add the code to my own form but I have this error:

"No attachment detected".

I am not a developer, so I'm a little confuse when I talk about code, sorry for that :(

This is my code:

```
 <label for="cv">Votre votre CV
     <span class="obligatoire">*</span>
 </label>
 <input type="file" class="validate[required,custom[cv]]" name="cv" class="cv" value="Votre CV au format PDF ou word uniquement" />
```

and the code in reception:

```
$allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "pdf");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["cv"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["cv"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["cv"]["type"] == "application/msword"))

&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["cv"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Error: " . $_FILES["cv"]["error"] ."')</script>";
    }
  else
    {
        $d='telechargements/emploi/cv/';
        $de=$d . basename($_FILES['cv']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"], $de);
        $fileName = $_FILES['cv']['name'];
        $filePath = $_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'];
        //add only if the file is an upload
     }
  }
else
  {
        echo "<script>alert('Invalid file')</script>";
  }

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email']);
$mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email']);
$mail->Subject = "Site Collin : Une réponse à l'offre de ".mb_strtolower($_POST['job'])."";
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['cv']['name']);
```

For me, there is no error, so I don't understand why the file is not detected during the post.

Somebody can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: mention path of the attached file.

Comment: Are you including the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `form` label?

Comment: @DonnieRock -> Yes ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your HTML form . You are not letting user to select a file as you already filled value field with data witch is not a file  value="Votre CV au format PDF ou word uniquement".

it should look something like

```
<input type="file" name="cv" />
```

that way your POST will have a cv field with a value of file path.

don't forget enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form.

Comment: It's working! Yeah, great thanks!

I don't understand why just because a value is added all the system blocked :-(